# Javascript function call is not working

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayDate()

{
alert("hi");
 var d=new Date();
 var theDay=d.getDay();
 switch (theDay)
 {
 case 5:
   document.write("Finally Friday");
   break;
 case 6:
   document.write("Super Saturday");
   break;
 case 0:
   document.write("Sleepy Sunday");
   break;
 default:
   document.write("I'm looking forward to this weekend!");
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph</p>
alert("before function call");
<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
alert("after function call");
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see you have javascript alert call inside of html and not inside script tags.  Have you checked to see if you have error in the console?

Comment: actually i am practicing javascript in notepad(windows) so nothing out there in console. although i could see the alert statements in the console as such.

Comment: @abson When you open the document in the browser, you can always see the console, letting you know there is a syntax error.

Comment: @abson Just to be clear, they're referring to a debugger console -- Firebug or those built into Chrome, IE8+, etc. -- which will list syntax errors such as the "unexpected end" you should've been getting. Most can be opened with F12 and define `console.log` as a better alternative to `alert` debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

function has not } at last

```
function displayDate()
{
alert("hi");
 var d=new Date();
 var theDay=d.getDay();
 switch (theDay)
 {
 case 5:
   document.write("Finally Friday");
   break;
 case 6:
   document.write("Super Saturday");
   break;
 case 0:
   document.write("Sleepy Sunday");
   break;
 default:
   document.write("I'm looking forward to this weekend!");
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks @hkutluay for the patience to help me out

Comment: again what is the best way for learning javascript?

Comment: you're welcome.. best way is writing more as other languages :) and learn how to debug javascript with developer tools etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing a } at the end of your function.

Checking syntax is the first thing you want to do when something isn't working as intended. Also, checking to see if there's a javascript error in your browser when testing :)

Answer (score 0):

I just now tested your code and it is working with a few modifications :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayDate()

{
alert("hi");
 var d=new Date();
 var theDay=d.getDay();
 switch (theDay)
 {
 case 5:
   document.write("Finally Friday");
   break;
 case 6:
   document.write("Super Saturday");
   break;
 case 0:
   document.write("Sleepy Sunday");
   break;
 default:
   document.write("I'm looking forward to this weekend!");
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```